# Certain Switch Cases not printing Java

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, switch-statement

I have a Switch statement within a loop where I am trying to print a random math operation in an equation multiple times. The whole code is quite long, so I'm hoping this is enough to answer my question.
I know for certain that the fifth case '%' does not work.

Here is my output

```
            num1 = random.nextInt(max + 1 - min) + min;
            num2 = random.nextInt(max + 1 - min) + min;

            char op = switch (getOper(year)) {
                case 1 -> '+';
                case 2 -> '-';
                case 3 -> '*';
                case 4 -> '/';
                case 5 -> '%';
                default -> ' ';
            };

            //prints out the questions
            System.out.print(num1 + " " + op + " " + num2 + " = ");


         private int getOper(int year){
            //sets the operatorBounds variable to zero
            int operatorBounds = 1;
            //creates a new random object
            Random bounds = new Random();
            int oper = 0;

            //determines how many operations are available to each year level
            if (year == 1 || year == 2){
                operatorBounds = 2;
                oper = bounds.nextInt(operatorBounds);
            } else if (year == 3 || year == 4 || year == 5){
                operatorBounds = 4;
                oper = bounds.nextInt(operatorBounds);
            } else if (year == 6 || year == 7){
                operatorBounds = 5;
                oper = bounds.nextInt(operatorBounds);
            }
            return oper;
        }
```

This is the output I'm receiving:

```
6674   2640 = 1560 + -5740 = 1274   6126 =
```

The spaces are where the operator is supposed to be

If anyone can help I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: probably they return the default value. Has it occurred to you that we have no idea what 'year' has as value, and thus can't possibly know the outcome? have you debugged your code?

Comment: `nextInt(5)` will return a number between 0 inclusive, and 5 **exclusive**, that is, one integer of `0`, `1` ... `4`, but **never** `5` (and all the other `if` cases will return even smaller numbers) [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)): "*Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)*"

Comment: @user16320675 I completely overlooked that! thank you so much

Comment: you get the default case if `nextInt` returns 0 or if not `1 <= year <= 7`